# Export all data to excel including data from pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I'm working on a table that can export data to excel using [js excel generator](https://github.com/ecscstatsconsulting/js-excel-generator). It work somehow, my problem is I cant display all the data, it only display the current data shown.

hope you help me.

thanks.

```
$("#toExcel").click(function () {
      var filename = $('title').text();
        excel = new ExcelGen({
            "src_id": "excelGen_table",
            "show_header": true
        });
        excel.generate();
    });
```

Comment: As per its documentation it will generate excel if table is already created in dom, so in your case if table is having pagination then it might be displaying table with limited rows that's why it is not exporting all data. Alternatively you can create table with all rows and hide it from displaying from main page and when you want to export to excel then use that table only instead of table which user is viewing. Hope this will help.

Comment: I see, thanks for that